# Is there a spatial gradient in my data

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, regression, correlation

I already posted the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218956/is-there-a-spatial-gradient-in-my-data), but I thought that maybe it is a question for GIS as well.

I have a grid with densities of one animal and would like to find out if there is a spatial gradient in relation to density (i.e. is density increasing/decreasing from north to south).

So I actually have two questions:

1. Is density increasing with direction?
2. In what direction is density increasing?

What would be the appropriate way to do this analysis?

I would prefer R for stats and plotting. GIS tools work out fine as well (ArcGIS or QGIS).

The data looks like this:

```
density          lat            long
0.15             55.32512       10.21354
0.25             55.20000       10.17561
0.35             55.12002       10.51156
...              ...            ...
```

**EDIT**
Here is more example data:

```
density,lat,long
0.531281,55.526,10.576
0.616255,55.526,10.676
0,55.526,10.776
0.220244,55.526,10.876
0.340568,55.526,10.976
0.169816,55.526,11.076
0.738845,55.526,11.176
0,55.526,11.276
0.922441,55.526,11.376
0.351356,55.526,11.476
0,55.526,11.576
0.196834,55.526,11.676
0.413896,55.526,11.776
0.415515,55.526,11.876
0.829232,55.476,10.476
0.773095,55.476,10.576
0.206307,55.476,10.676
0.965093,55.476,10.776
0,55.476,10.876
0.623462,55.476,10.976
0,55.476,11.076
0.096898,55.476,11.176
0,55.476,11.276
0.105268,55.476,11.376
0.358446,55.476,11.476
0,55.476,11.576
0.104524,55.476,11.676
0,55.476,11.776
0.11956,55.476,11.876
0,55.426,10.476
0.848671,55.426,10.576
0.623913,55.426,10.676
0.412585,55.426,10.776
0,55.426,10.876
0.32173,55.426,10.976
0.413574,55.426,11.076
0.19461,55.426,11.176
0,55.426,11.276
0.105246,55.426,11.376
0.521221,55.426,11.476
0.767538,55.426,11.576
0,55.426,11.676
0.220289,55.426,11.776
0,55.426,11.876
0,55.376,10.476
0.119743,55.376,10.576
0.423292,55.376,10.676
0.210504,55.376,10.776
0,55.376,10.876
0.421375,55.376,10.976
0,55.376,11.076
0.898533,55.376,11.176
0,55.376,11.276
0,55.376,11.376
0.220306,55.376,11.476
0,55.376,11.576
0.209429,55.376,11.676
0,55.376,11.776
0,55.376,11.876
0.358789,55.326,10.576
0.676287,55.326,10.676
0.885888,55.326,10.776
0.211766,55.326,10.876
0.210419,55.326,10.976
0.405206,55.326,11.076
0.791464,55.326,11.176
0.238843,55.326,11.276
0.119407,55.326,11.376
0.430063,55.326,11.476
0.238774,55.326,11.576
0,55.326,11.676
0.340171,55.276,10.576
0.52553,55.276,10.676
0.362389,55.276,10.776
0.229836,55.276,10.876
0.833,55.276,10.976
0.492536,55.276,11.076
0.316279,55.276,11.176
0,55.276,11.276
0.522459,55.276,11.376
0.419986,55.276,11.476
0.478506,55.276,11.576
1.464888,55.276,11.676
0.830414,55.226,10.576
0.561281,55.226,10.676
0,55.226,10.776
0.105163,55.226,10.876
0.105216,55.226,10.976
1.383348,55.226,11.076
0.40435,55.226,11.176
0.210608,55.226,11.276
0.839,55.226,11.376
0.328165,55.226,11.476
0,55.226,11.576
0.101332,55.176,10.676
0.421495,55.176,10.776
0.105216,55.176,10.876
0.396272,55.176,10.976
1.492883,55.176,11.076
0.420884,55.176,11.176
1.039168,55.176,11.276
0.417179,55.176,11.376
0,55.176,11.476
0.238649,55.176,11.576
0.401279,55.126,10.676
0.776657,55.126,10.776
0.441379,55.126,10.876
0.10527,55.126,10.976
0.432764,55.126,11.076
0.501523,55.126,11.176
0,55.126,11.276
0,55.126,11.376
0.121543,55.126,11.476
0,55.126,11.576
0,55.076,10.676
0.680252,55.076,10.776
0.318412,55.076,10.876
0.119464,55.076,10.976
0.124579,55.076,11.076
0,55.076,11.176
0,55.076,11.276
0,55.076,11.376
0,55.076,11.476
0.60003,55.026,10.776
0,55.026,10.876
0,55.026,10.976
0,55.026,11.076
```

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218956/is-there-a-spatial-gradient-in-my-data - please do not cross-post: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4067/cross-posting-duplicate-questions-to-different-communities

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to look at a multivariate regression in R.

Let us assume that you have create a `data.frame` with your `density`, `lat` & `lon`. Then you can do something along these lines (rough outline taken from [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html)):

```
# Multiple Linear Regression
fit <- lm(density ~ lat + lon, data=DensityDataFrame)
summary(fit) # show results
# Other useful functions 
coefficients(fit) # model coefficients
confint(fit, level=0.95) # CIs for model parameters 
fitted(fit) # predicted values
residuals(fit) # residuals
vcov(fit) # covariance matrix for model parameters 
influence(fit) # regression diagnostics
#Diagnostic Plots
#Diagnostic plots provide checks for heteroscedasticity, normality, and influential observerations.
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2)) # optional 4 graphs/page 
plot(fit)
```

Another, simpler, approach would be to look at north-south and east-west separately by simply throwing away the `lat` or the `lon` and then doing a simple linear regression accompanied by a scatterplot. With a bit of trigonometry you can also rotate your axis and do the simple analysis along the northwest-southeast axis, or northeast-southwest.

As for understanding what the output means, you get a lot of directionality information from the coefficients that the model gives you. If you reproject your data into a more suitable coordinate system (such as UTM), you will be able to consider the coeeficients provided by the model as a kind of directionality vectors.

Comment: + 1, but it is better not to work with Lat/long for spatial regression analysis. At 55 ° of latitude, one degree from West to east is 0.57* one degree from North to South

Comment: Good point, @radouxju but one can always reproject to a more suitable coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks, that would give me the answer to Question 1. I actually did this with only using two variables (density and lat or density and long) not beeing aware that I can combine both. However, the result seems to be for each individual variable and not for a combination of both. Or am I misinterpreting the results? And I still lack the answer to question 2. "In what direction is density increasing?"

Comment: I don't have a suitable dataset to test with, so I can't really tell you how to exactly interpret the results. Can you provide an extended example,  @Alex?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question with more data.